# PHP Function to check value in Array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to come up with a function in order to get me some specific data from an array. It's part of a permissions system I am doing for a page.

Here is the array of data I have:

```
[views] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [permItem] => viewOriginalFeedback
                        [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [view] => 0
                                [edit] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [permItem] => viewTarget
                        [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [view] => 0
                                [edit] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

What I am trying to do is create a function where I can pass is pass it a perm item and action like so. `if(myFunction('viewOriginalFeedback', 'view'))` if this returns 1 I show the content, if its a 0 then I know to not show it.

The issue is that these `views` may not exist at all in the array so in that case it would be `false` as if the action was set to `0`.

I was playing around with something like this but I feel like there is a more elegant way to complete it.

```
// Permission Check
function checkPerm($permItem, $action){
    foreach($permissions->data->views as $view){

        if($view->permItem == $permItem){

            if($view->actions == $action){
                    return $view->actions->$action;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `if(isset($view->actions->$action))` and I would probably go for an associative array instead of array of objects.

Comment: you're code looks fine, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler and not require looping to use an associative array:

```
Array
(
    [viewOriginalFeedback] => Array
        (
            [view] => 0
            [edit] => 0
        )

    [viewTarget] => Array
        (
            [view] => 0
            [edit] => 0
        )

)
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
if(isset($permissions[$permItem][$action])) {
    return (bool)$permissions[$permItem][$action];
}
return false;
```

You could maintain the use of objects and still keep it simple with a string key:

```
[viewOriginalFeedback] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [permItem] => viewOriginalFeedback
                    [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [view] => 0
                            [edit] => 0
                        )

                )
```

With the same check:

```
if(isset($permissions[$permItem]->actions->$action)) {
    return (bool)$permissions[$permItem]->actions->$action;
}
return false;
```

With your current array of objects your current approach is probably the way to go, but more like:

```
foreach($permissions->data->views as $view){
    if($view->permItem == $permItem){
        if(isset($view->actions->$action)){
            return (bool)$view->actions->$action;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems like this would be the best way to go. However, I am trying to look at modifying my SQL to provide the needed format for this. I use TSQL and output it as XML so I need to get the format correct.

Comment: Added a case for your current array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the example and the array contains `0` for the value of `edit` but the output is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking advantage of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to shorten the code. This assumes that you can't convert to using an associative array like AbraCadaver suggested. It's also slightly less efficient than your own code because array_filter will walk the rest of the array, even after it has found the first match.

```
function checkPerm($permItem, $action){
    $val = array_filter($permissions->data->views, function($v) {
        return $v->permItem === $permItem;
    });
    return isset($vals[0]->$action) && (bool) $vals[0]->$action;
}
```